# Gradle Build Error java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm getting a grade build error when i want to launch my project. It goes like that:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException (no error message)
```

I copy pasted some stuff into this project, which caused a few errors before, so it might be an error because of copy/pasting...

Here is my build.grade files:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and another build.gradle file:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.leodr.upgradeadmin"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/gson-1.4.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I hope you can help me, TY for your help!

Comment: Update your gradle build tools, add the new google repository and sync project.

Comment: How can i do that? I don't know that much about gradle and all that stuff...

Answer (score 0):

Update your project level `build.grade`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and your module level `build.gradle` :

Change these line:

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
```

to:

```
compileSdkVersion 27 //buildToolsVersion is not needed
```

and:

```
targetSdkVersion 26
```

to:

```
targetSdkVersion 27
```

and the dependency line:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
```

to:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
```

Now sync your project and if it prompts your to download just click on the link in the error to download.

Comment: now i get the following error: Error:(6, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'google()'
Possible causes:<ul><li>The project 'UPGradeAdmin' may be using a version of Gradle that does not contain the method.
<a href="open.wrapper.file">Open Gradle wrapper file</a></li><li>The build file may be missing a Gradle plugin.
<a href="apply.gradle.plugin">Apply Gradle plugin</a></li>

Comment: @thisw4y Update Android Studio, click on help -> check for updates